# What's the purpose of asynchronous generators in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, iterator, generator

I'm reading a book on Modern Asynchronous Javascript, and at one point the author writes some code to query a Github repo and retrieve all of its past commits.

The resulting array gives us 30 commits at a time, and the response header provides us with a link to the next page that contains additional results.

In the book, the author uses a generator function to accomplish this task like this:

```js
    async function* generator(repo) {
      for (;;) {
        const response = await axios.get(repo, config);
        const data = response.data;
        for (let commit of data) {
          yield commit;
        }
        const link = response.headers.link;
        repo = /<(.*?)>; rel="next"/.exec(link)?.[1];
    
        if (repo === undefined) {
          // Breaking doesn't return anything, which means the iterator is done
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    async function getCommits(repo, maxData) {
      let i = 0;
      for await (const commit of generator(repo)) {
        console.log(`-------------repo: ${i}-----------------`);
        console.log(commit);
        if (i++ === maxData) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

In trying to understand generator functions, I ended up rewriting this code how I would normally do it with a regular asynchronous function like this:

```js
    async function getCommits(url, numItems) {
      let i = 0;
    
      while (i <= numItems) {
        let commits = await axios.get(url, config);
        let data = commits.data;
        let nextUrl = /<(.*?)>; rel="next"/.exec(commits.headers.link)?.[1];
        for (let commit of data) {
          if (i > numItems) break;
          console.log(`-------------repo: ${i}-----------------`);
          console.log(commit);
          i++;
        }
        url = nextUrl;
      }
    }
```

My code seems to work fine, and it seems to be shorter than the version using the generator function. I still don't fully understand the use-case for asynchronous generators or why I would ever use them.

Would love if someone could explain or point me towards some resources for learning more.

Comment: Your code does not stop properly when `nextUrl` is nullish, and you need to repeat the `numItems` comparison twice. The `generator` function is just more generic and reusable.

Comment: The true purpose of generators is to simplify creation of iterable objects.

Answer (score 1):

One of the purposes is to *abstract* the asynchronous actions. Say there's a library that has a function that does a number of asynchronous tasks. While it *could* instruct users of the library to perform the iterations themselves - such as with your second code - it's arguably nicer to provide users with an async generator instead.

If you implement the generator *once*, that generator can then be used wherever it's needed, instead of having to write imperative iterative code.

It's nicer to be able to say

```
// Here's how you use this library
for await (const result of getResults()) {
  console.log(result);
}
```

than

```
// Here's how you use this library
let i = 0;
const resultsGetter = makeAllResultsGetter();
while (i <= numItems) {
  const result = await resultsGetter();
  console.log(result);
  i++;
}
```

You definitely don't *need* to use async generators, but you may one time come across a situation where you find that the logic pattern they provide is the most elegant approach to the problem at hand.